# Terraform set AMI permissions to public

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ami

I'm currently using Terraform to copy an AMI from one region to multiple regions using:

```
resource "aws_ami_copy" "my_ami" {
  name              = "my_ami-${var.region}"
  source_ami_id     = "${var.source_ami_id}"
  source_ami_region = "${var.source_ami_region}"
}
```

I need to make this AMI public, I've looked online and I can't find a way to do this using Terraform.

Comment: is your source ami public?

Comment: It could be, i'm generating the source AMI too. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform doesn't have a native way to do this currently. You can normally use Terraform to share an AMI with another account using the [`aws_ami_launch_permission` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ami_launch_permission.html) but this only supports adding specific accounts and not the `all` group required for making it public.

You could always use a `local-exec` provisioner to shell out to the [AWS CLI to make the AMI public](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/sharingamis-intro.html#sharingamis-cli) with something like:

```
resource "null_resource" "share_ami_publicly" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws ec2 modify-image-attribute --image-id ami-12345678 --launch-permission '{\"Add\":[{\"Group\":\"all\"}]}'"
  }
}
```

Where the provisioner could be attached to any relevant resource (such as the [`aws_ami` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ami.html) if you are using that to create AMIs).